# Connect multiple devices to one power cord

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage

I have one Canon power cord (below I have include an image), for connecting one camera directly to power and not using a battery. I want to connect two or more cameras to it. This power cord has output 7.4V and  2.0A. For connecting two devices (doing the suitable soldering of course). Are 7.4V and 2A enough or do I need to buy a different cord with more Amperes? Is the formula like 4 ampere for 2 devices 6 ampere for 3 etc or am I wrong? I think I need to keep the voltage untouched.

[image]

Comment: If you connect three cameras to one power supply (PSU) and each camera needs 2A to charge, your 2A charger will not be able to supply the 6A needed. It might be better (and faster) to charge the three cameras one after another sequentially. If you can buy a 7.4V 6A PSU you should be able to charge three cameras concurrently.

Comment: If you are not connecting the batteries, the current used will be lower. You still want to measure it, and measure it with the light on and lcd on and everything. If its a camera and not a camcorder, take some flash pictures while measuring it to find the highest current draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct!

You are making a [parallel](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/physics/phys03/bparcir/default.htm) [circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits), so:

$$V_\text{total} = V_1 = V_2 = V_n$$

$$I_\text{total}=I_1+I_2+I_n$$

The current you have to sum, so if one camera needs 2A, the total current will be:

*Number of Cameras times 2A.*

The voltage is the same for every camera, so you need ensure 7.4V.

You need to do something like this:

[image]

Where **V** its you power supply and each **R** are your cameras.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see what exactly your camera draws in amps when it is charging. This can easily be measured using a multimeter. 
[image]

The charging circuit found within your camera might be using the full 2 amps or it might not.

I would recommend only doing one split and ONLY doing that split if your current draw for both devices doesn't go over about 1.6ish amps.

Play it safe and don't burn anything down.

Good Luck!